# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Intellisense not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, intellisense

SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Intellisense is not working.

I have already enabled Intellisense.
I have already cleared the cache.

Comment: Michael, welcome to Stack Overflow!  We're glad that you've chosen to share your knowledge with the community - having battled with Intellisense a few times myself, I like the tip you've shared.  Unfortunately, there's a little bit of cleanup required - you have both the question and the answer stored in the question.  Try reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and see how to do this next time!  Spend a little time on the site gaining reputation, and you'll be able to immediately answer your own question in the future.

Comment: To clarify - if you want to keep this around, I'd suggest first copying everything after "there was one fix I found" into an answer on this page; second, edit your original post to remove the 'answer' portion; and third, try adding more detail to your question (like links to solutions you tried that did not work). Failing that, another option would be to add your solution as an additional answer to the questions you found on the website trying to deal with the same topic - posting an answer that says, "the solution may have worked for you, but I had to also do x" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @AHiggins It [requires 15 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question.

Comment: @BaconBits, I assume that _"Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time."_ will allow them to post an (unaccepted < 48 hours) answer

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

There was one fix I found after fumbling through the different users, and it was a permissions issue: Make sure the login users has access to the `xp_instance_regread` stored procedure in the Master database. The command to give access is as follows:

```
USE master 
GO 
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_instance_regread TO YourLoggedInUser;
```